# Is there a way to find in a text the places where the "superscript spanned strings" are existing, and respan them as bold?

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

Is there a way to find in a `TextView` the places where the "**superscript spanned strings**" are existing, and respan them as bold?

For example `index(start:13, end 15), index(start 25, end 33)` etc. And then reapply a bold span to them. Any ideas?

Comment: You should save the indices when you made them superscript and reuse them again

Comment: @Zain thank you, but it will be very complex if I do so

Comment: complex some how .. but you can do that with Room database easily, if you would some skeleton .. please let me know

Comment: @Zain I don't have enough knowledge about that. Can you explain a step by step post about it? I accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't directly get specific styled portions  (**superscript** in your case) of `TextView`.

To solve this you need to save the start/end indices when you made them superscript and reuse them again when you need to bold them.

You can have a data/pojo class that stores: id, startIndex, endIndex, styleType...etc

Then you can use this data class to build up a `Room` database.

You can [check documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room) to find out how to build up a Room database, also you can check [this](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-room-database-example/) for a complete example

But here I will give a skeleton

**Data/Pojo class**

```
@Entity(tableName = "spannable_data")
public class SpannableData {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;
    int styleType;
    int startIndex;
    int endIndex;

    @Ignore
    public SpannableData(int styleType, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        this.styleType = styleType;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    public SpannableData(int id, int styleType, int startIndex, int endIndex) {
        this.id = id;
        this.styleType = styleType;
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getStyleType() {
        return styleType;
    }

    public void setStyleType(int styleType) {
        this.styleType = styleType;
    }

    public int getStartIndex() {
        return startIndex;
    }

    public void setStartIndex(int startIndex) {
        this.startIndex = startIndex;
    }

    public int getEndIndex() {
        return endIndex;
    }

    public void setEndIndex(int endIndex) {
        this.endIndex = endIndex;
    }
}
```

**Dao class**

```
@Dao
public
interface SpannableDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    void insertSpan(SpannableData spannableData);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM spannable_data WHERE styleType = :type")
    List<SpannableData> getSpans(int type);

    @Query("DELETE FROM spannable_data WHERE styleType = :type")
    void deleteSpans(int type);

    @Query("DELETE FROM spannable_data")
    void deleteAllSpans();

    @Delete
    void deleteSpan(SpannableData spannableData);

}
```

**Database class**

```
@Database(entities = {SpannableData.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)

public abstract class SpannableDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase.db";

    private static volatile SpannableDatabase INSTANCE;

    // used from synchronization (to avoid any race conditions) so that make sure that two parts of the app don’t try to create the database at the same time
    private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

    public abstract SpannableDao getSpannableDao();

    static public SpannableDatabase getInstance(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (LOCK) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            SpannableDatabase.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            .build();
                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }

}
```